# React-Redux: Why do we need to wrap the component with Provider?

Tags: reactjs, redux

The best practice for using Redux in React application is wrapping the component in a 'Provider' component:

```
const rootElement = document.getElementById('root')
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <TodoApp />
  </Provider>,
  rootElement
)
```

You can see it in React-Redux documentation: https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial.

What is the benefit we get from this attitude? 
Why not just importing the 'store' inside the 'ToDoApp' component and access 'store' as an imported variable? For example:

```
import { store } from './store';

class TodoApp extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log('constructor')
  }
  render() {
    console.log(store.getState());
  }
}
```

Comment: It is an easy way to make React component aware of the store and rerender when we change store. Also, it is convenient to not always pass down the store, especially for third parties component, where you don't have the source code, so you can't import store, you will have to pass it as a prop. The main argument is convenience I would say.

Comment: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/7402f728c5948cbf01fb07086dcb1ec66968a044/website/versioned_docs/version-7.x/using-react-redux/accessing-store.md

Answer (score 2):

The actual point that is happening in the redux, when we are calling the provider: that it is having the store of all the states and the provider does the job to connect the component with the redux or simply you can say that the provider does the job to connect your app with the redux as the author of the redux has not only to design the library for a single framework, it would have so many uses on different platforms, the store is having two things inside (reducers and state) and all the states get an outer layer of provider which connects the app with the redux library.

Answer (score 0):

This is very important to the way `react-redux` works.

When you use `connect` over your component, it attempts to get the store from the `Provider` you set, using React's context mechanism.

It is highly unlikely that you will use Redux in React without using `connect`, so I would advise that you keep it there.